# What should linux-menu-group be when creating JPackage installer Java application on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jpackage

What are the norms for creating JPackage installer Java application on  Linux ?

I have created an installer for Windows, and am now creating one on Linux (using Ubuntu)

So far I have:

```
-i target/Jaikoz/buildLinux
--main-class com.jthink.jaikoz.Jaikoz
--name Jaikoz 
--main-jar lib/jaikoz.jar
--app-version 10.1.0
--copyright "Copyright 2020 JThink Ltd, United Kingdom"
--arguments "-l2 -m2 -f" --java-options "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
--java-options "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
--vendor JThink
--icon "Jaikoz64.png"
--install-dir /opt
--linux-menu-group Jaikoz
--linux-shortcut
```

for creating a debian installer, it works (installs not yet running properly) but I am confused about a number of things, I am not so familiar with the linux environment.

- Cannot see the effect of *linux-menu-group* or *linux-shortcut*
- Should I be using *linux-menu-group* or *linux-app-category*, and if so is it a predefined list ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### linux-menu-group

`--linux-menu-group` defines the `categories` (separated by `;`) under which the application will be classified.

There is a **connection between desktop start menu entries and categories** but categories are more generic. However by specifying e.g. `Education` as a value, you will see your application shortcut appearing on the `Education` group of the main menu (of the desktop start menu).

If your category does not match an existing one it will be added to `Other` menu section.

Technical-wise, the categories you provide (via `--linux-menu-group`) will be added in the `category` attribute of a [desktop entry descriptor file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) (`*.desktop`) ([See Desktop Menu Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html#main-category-registry)).
The combination of [*.menu](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/ar01s04.html) files and directories containing `*.desktop` files constructs the various menus.

**Possible values for `linux-menu-group`:**

- [Main categories](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html)
- [Additional categories](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apas02.html)
- [Reserved categories](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apas03.html)

[vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for example uses this value: `Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;`

#### linux-shortcut

If you don't provide `--linux-shortcut` you will not get a menu shortcut. I'm not sure if there is any reason providing `--linux-menu-group` if you have not provided the above.

#### linux-app-category

`--linux-app-category` **it is unrelated to the desktop menu shortcuts.** It corresponds to the `Section` field of `*.deb` file and "specifies an application area into which the package has been classified". [Ref](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-section)

It's like a classification for the type of software (e.g. when searching for packages).

Possible values are described [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections)

Comment: Thx, so if I want to use Audio from main categories it says I also have to use Audio/Video so do I do it like this --linux-menu-group=AudioVideo, Audio.

Comment: I don't think you "should". You could just use `Audio`. But if you decide to use more categories don't forget to separate with `;` (instead of `,` ).

Comment: @PaulTaylor Oh ok, I just saw the [notes](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html) for `Audio`: "Desktop entry must include AudioVideo as well". Then yes:  `--linux-menu-group="AudioVideo;Audio;"` (add a `;` at the end also)